# PHP/MYSQL: Importing csv files through php into a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have been trying this code I found from this site here: https://www.johnboyproductions.com/blog/tutorial-import-a-csv-file-using-php-and-mysql

It works perfectly for me locally, but when I try the code on a live site. It says that the data is imported but does not reflect in the database. I am adding the code below:

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

//get the csv file 
$file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
$handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

//loop through the csv file and insert into database 
do { 
    if ($data[0]) { 
        mysqli_query("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES 
            ( 
                '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                '".addslashes($data[1])."'
            ) 
        "); 
    } 
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
// 

//redirect 
header('Location: filename.php?success=1'); die; 

}
```

That's the functionality part, I will post the form section below:

```
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
            Choose your file: <br /> 
            <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> 
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
            </form>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: are your databases setup correctly? Have you tried to add any debug code to see where something is failing? Do you have rw permission to create/upload files?

Comment: It gave no issues locally. The same database

Comment: In addition to the previous comment check csv size and server post max size and upload max size

Comment: You can comment out redirect part if the code and print something in the while to see if it enters in it

Comment: Same database... hosted locally?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake. `addslashes` is **NOT** a substitute for proper escaping.

Comment: @ElefantPhace Yes

Comment: @krasipenkov I will try that

Comment: Is your live site being hosted from the same machine with access to the local database? And if not then does the remote server have access to your local machine with your database? Or should you create the database on the remote server?

Comment: It is on a remote server

Comment: @krasipenkov It does display Hello when I add `echo "Hello";`

Comment: What is the output if you place var_dump of mysqli_query?

Comment: Ok I followed a similar code that was done somewhere else, and it is working now. I will post it below. Thank you all for the assistance :)

Comment: See the difference between them :) mysqli_query - in the first approach connection parameter is missing

Comment: I need to be more cautious about these things. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried another code that was used initially which is working now:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{

if ($_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0)
{ 

//get the csv file 
$file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']; 
$handle = fopen($file,"r"); 


$firstRow = true;

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{

if($firstRow) { $firstRow = false; }
else {

 $str="INSERT INTO tablename VALUES 
            ('' ,
                '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                '".addslashes($data[1])."'
            ) ";




            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$str);
            if($result)
                $cnt++;
}
}

fclose($handle);

//redirect 
// header('Location: filename.php?success=1'); die; 

} 


}
```